# EditText setError all at once

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have multiple EditTexts in a register form. The problem is when I click the button it displays a validation message only for the first EditText. After I fill in data for the first EditText and I click the submit button again, it only shows an error for 2nd edittext.

Is there way to show a message for all of them at once?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are validating your UI inputs once after a button got pressed.  On click of a button you can validate all input field's data and you can create a result string with all the errors based on their validation and you can display that error message as a message dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You need a method like this:

```
public boolean allFieldsAreFine(){
    boolean allFieldsAreFine = true;

    if (!isValidField(editText1.getText().toString())){
        allFieldsAreFine = false;
        editText1.setError("Invalid field.");
    }
    if (!isValidField(editText2.getText().toString())){
        allFieldsAreFine = false;
        editText2.setError("Invalid field.");
    }
    .
    .
    .
    if (!isValidField(editTextN.getText().toString())){
        allFieldsAreFine = false;
        editTextN.setError("Invalid field.");
    }

    return allFieldsAreFine;
}
```

I hope you can understand my idea.